# ChangePasswordAtLogon not applying on New-ADUser when enabled is false

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

Using powershell 2.0, I have a simple script to create a **New-ADUser**. The user must change their password on next logon and the account must be disabled. This works until I create the account in disabled mode.

According to the documentation, ensuring **PasswordNeverExpires** is **$false** will allow for change password at logon, but that didn't help. Would anyone know why **ChangePasswordAtLogon** isn't applying if **enabled** is set to false?

Code (I have included the other settings I am using in case they matter):

```
New-ADUser -Name "NewPerson" `
           -Path "DC=WhereEver" `
           -AccountPassword $SecureStringHere `
           -PasswordNeverExpires $False `
           -ChangePasswordAtLogon $True `
           -enabled $False `
           -UserPrinciplaName "NewPerson" `
           -DisplayName "NewPerson" `
           -Description "NewPerson" `
           -ProfilePath "path" `
           -ScriptPath "path"
```

If you don't know how to fix this any ideas on what could be going wrong are appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's the password that causes the effect, although I can't explain why. The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx) doesn't say anything about this AFAICS. Remove `-ChangePasswordAtLogon $True` from the `New-ADUser` statement and set the option afterwards via

```
Set-ADUser -Identity 'NewPerson' -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
```

and the account should be created the way you expect.

Comment: `New-ADUser ... -PassThru | Set-ADUder -ChangePasswordAtLogon:$true`. Reason is that an account having a valid password is a precondition for a password change. The password argument may violate/fail a password filter/policy when you create the user, and so `ChangePasswordAtLogon` cannot be guaranteed

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The password does meet the requirements, but taking ChangePasswordAtLogon out of the New-AdUser seems to be working. thanks!